# Double Cross Dipole antenna for 437 MHz don't tune

Tags: antenna, uhf, dipole, satellites, phased-array

I'm building a **Double Cross Dipole antenna** for 437 MHz to be used with a SDR receiver for CW cubesat.
The idea is to follow [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1q-psxlp3IwamN0VFZORmw3UjQ/view?usp=sharing) "classic" paper from ***Gerald Martes, KD6JDJ***.
I tuned every single dipole (8 mm aluminium bar + ferrite + coax cable) using a *nanoVNA* with - i think - good result(eg. here the return loss of first dipole)

[image]

I use a coax cable to measure the SWR like this

[image]

and the coax length is taken from end of the shield (as in this images :))

[image]
but when I connect all the 4 dipole ... **craziest thing happened** ...and it seems to me that every dipole change the proper resonant frequency to a different one.

[image]

Is **the problem** in the cabling between all the dipole ? Or (as I suppose) **I followed a wrong apporoach tuning separately every dipole** and the proper way is to tune **all the arms** after connect them together?

Can someone give me some hints on how to proceed?

Tks a lot

Carlo, IU2KQB

Comment: Welcome to hamSE, Carlo. According to the article, the behavior should not depend strongly on the tuning of individual elements; this might mean that the best approach is to make all four elements the same length. Is the SWR measurement made at the input to the coax "harness?" How did you ensure that the longer coax is $\frac{\lambda}{4}$ longer than the shorter coax?

Comment: Tks a lot for your warm welcome! Add some clarification in my post!

Comment: um, at 437 MHz,  I don't think you're doing yourself a favor adding these huge metal contacts to the system - these will have very distinct RF properties by themselves. Do things get better when you not use them and directly e.g. solder your dipole branches to the coax conductors?

Comment: by the way, what kind of coax is this?

Comment: Tks Marcus for your answer. I use a Messi&Paoloni cable named Hyperflex 5 (fi 5.4 mm / 50 Ohm / vf =0.87). The idea to use the metal clip is to avoid soldering aluminium and to calculate it in the total length of the dipole's arm...but I agree with you that is not one of the my best ideas :) and i ll use copper tube in my next try for sure

Comment: @CarloIU2KQB Perhaps you should contact the author. The article shows his email address. My NEC-2 simulation produces a very different pattern, with a clear "null" at the zenith, so I have no confidence in the SWR plot.

Comment: Wow,great.tks Can you share your NEC-2 model? i m just creating it so I can shorten a bit the task. Also, may be a silly question but can you esplain better your sentence about null and SWR ? You mean that this measure with a so complex pattern this kind is useless?

Comment: @CarloIU2KQB I don't think it is correct to post my work because it is not an answer to your question.

Comment: @BrianK1LI : No problem at all about not sharing your model! It is your work !!!

Comment: Just to complete this thread, i think is fundamental cite this [post](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16876/double-cross-antenna-whats-wrong-with-my-model) from @BrianK1LI. At the end...no one make mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the phasing and proper connection of the coax to the individual dipoles will get you a pretty good hemispherical CP pattern.  It is easy to get confused when connecting the coax to the dipole.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jerry! Do you recall if it's necessary to tune only the whole array rather than each dipole separately?

Comment: I would have some difficulty convincing anyone that the element diameter, or even its length is not critical. But, anyone familiar with computer modeling can do the evaluation.  The DCA is NOT an antenna which requires precision (at 137 MHz.

Comment: Hello Jerry, I have moved your callsign and email to your [profile](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/17404/jerry-martes?tab=profile).